# Is there a way to start a method from button click without using Update() function in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

Below is my C# script. I added a button to my project with a On Click event and called the Rotate() method. But for some reason it is not working

```
using System.Threading;
using UnityEngine;

public class Orbit : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject sun;
    public float speed;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    public void Update()
    {
        Rotate();
    }

    public void Rotate()
    {
        transform.RotateAround(sun.transform.position, Vector3.up, speed * 
        Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

I commented the Update() method when calling the Rotate() method. I also created a game object for the script.

Comment: You need to bind the `Rotate` method to a button. Edit: I see you've done that. Any errors? How did you set your OnClick event?

Comment: There were no errors. I created a button and to that button I added a Event trigger component and added the game object to the On Click()  method and called the Rotate() method.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why it's not working. I recommend you do a `Debug.Log("Working")` in your `Rotate` method to see if the function is called at all.

Comment: It seems that the function is not getting called when I add the button event. Without the button event it does get called. Thank you for your help @bolkay

Comment: The title is really confusing because it made me think you are speaking about [`Input.GetButton("XY")`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetButton.html). The `Update` has nothing to do with your `onClick` call of a `Button` component

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why it only works in `Update` currently is that

```
public void Rotate()
{
    transform.RotateAround(sun.transform.position, Vector3.up, speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

needs to be called repeatetly. Otherwise it will only rotate for exactly one frame and cause of `Time.deltaTime` only a very small amount. But the `onClick` event of the `Button` component is fired only once. It is similar to e.g. `Input.GetKeyDown` which is only called once when the key goes down. There is no implementation in the `Button` component itslef to handle a continued button press.

---

What you want instead as far as I understand is rotating the object after the button click

- start to rotate for ever
- for a certain duration
- until you press the button again
- until it is released (-> implement a continuesly firing button see below)

The `Button` component alone can only do the first three:

#### Rotate for ever

Either using a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)

```
private bool isRotating;

public void Rotate()
{
    // if aready rotating do nothing
    if(isRotating) return;

    // start the rotation
    StartCoroutine(RotateRoutine());

    isRotating = true;
}

private IEnumerator RotateRoutine()
{
    // whuut?!
    // Don't worry coroutines work a bit different
    // the yield return handles that .. never forget it though ;)
    while(true)
    {
         // rotate a bit
         transform.RotateAround(sun.transform.position, Vector3.up, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        // leave here, render the frame and continue in the next frame
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

or still doing it in `Update`

```
private bool isRotating = false;

private void Update()
{
    // if not rotating do nothing
    if(!isRotating) return;

    // rotate a bit
    transform.RotateAround(sun.transform.position, Vector3.up, speed * Time.deltaTime);
}

public void Rotate()
{
    // enable the rotation
    isRotating = true;
}
```

Note that the `Update` solution is only for your understanding what is happening. It should not be used like that because it is not that efficient since `Update` is called continously and checks the bool also if not rotating yet. That produces unnecessary overhead. The same applies to **all** following examples: Prefere to use the Coroutines over `Update` (**In this case!** In other cases it is actuall better and more efficient to use one `Update` method instead of multiple concurrent Coroutines .. but that's another story.)

#### Rotate for a certain duration

As Coroutine

```
// adjust in the inspector
// how long should rotation carry on (in seconds)?
public float duration = 1;

private bool isAlreadyRotating;

public void Rotate()
{
    // if aready rotating do nothing
    if(isAlreadyRotating) return;

    // start a rottaion
    StartCoroutine(RotateRoutine());
}

private IEnumerator RotateRoutine()
{
    // set the flag to prevent multiple callse
    isAlreadyRotating = true;

    float timePassed = 0.0f;
    while(timePassed < duration)
    {
         // rotate a small amount
         transform.RotateAround(sun.transform.position, Vector3.up, speed * Time.deltaTime);

         // add the time passed since last frame
         timePassed += Time.deltaTime;

         // leave here,  render the frame and continue in the next frame
         yield return null;
    }

    // reset the flag so another rotation might be started again
    isAlreadyRotating = false;
}
```

or in `Update`

```
public float duration;

private bool isRotating;
private float timer;

private void Update()
{
    // if not rotating do nothing
    if(!isRotating) return;

    // reduce the timer by passed time since last frame
    timer -= Time.deltaTime;

    // rotate a small amount
    transform.RotateAround(sun.transform.position, Vector3.up, speed * Time.deltaTime);

    // if the timer is not 0 return
    if(timer > 0) return;

    // stop rottaing
    isRotating = false;
}

public void Rotate()
{
    // if already rotating do nothing
    if(isRotating) return;

    // start rotating
    isRotating = true;

    // enable timer
    timer = duration;
}
```

#### Toggle rotation

This is very similar to the one before but this time instead of the timer you stop the rotation by clicking again. (You even could combine the two but than be carefull to reset the `isRotating` flag correctly ;) )

As Coroutine

```
private bool isRotating;

public void ToggleRotation()
{
    // if rotating stop the routine otherwise start one
    if(isRotating)
    {
        StopCoroutine(RotateRoutine());
        isRotating = false;
    }
    else
    {
        StartCoroutine(RotateRoutine());
        isRotating = true;
    }
}

private IEnumerator RotateRoutine()
{
    // whuut?!
    // Don't worry coroutines work a bit different
    // the yield return handles that .. never forget it though ;)
    while(true)
    {
        // rotate a bit
        transform.RotateAround(sun.transform.position, Vector3.up, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        // leave here, render the frame and continue in the next frame
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

or as `Update`

```
private bool isRotating;

private void Update()
{
    // if not rotating do nothing
    if(!isRottaing) return;

    // rotate a bit
    transform.RotateAround(sun.transform.position, Vector3.up, speed * Time.deltaTime);
}

public void ToggleRotation()
{
    // toggle the flag
    isRotating = !isRotating;
}
```

---

#### Rotate until released

This is the most "complicated" part since the `Button` alone can not accomplish this (there is no "on Release"). But you can implement this using [IPointerXHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerDownHandler.html) interfaces.

The good news: You can keep your original script as you have it currently

```
public void Rotate()
{
    transform.RotateAround(sun.transform.position, Vector3.up, speed * 
    Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Now you need an extension for the button. It will call the `whilePressed` event repeatedly every frame like `Update` so you just have to reference your `Rotate` method in `whilePressed` instead of the `onClick`.

Again there are two options either implementing it as a Coroutine:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Button))]
public class HoldableButton : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{
    // reference the same way as in onClick
    public UnityEvent whilePressed;       

    private Button button;
    private bool isPressed;

    private void Awake()
    {
        button = GetComponent<Button>();

        if(!button)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Oh no no Button component on this object :O",this);
        }
    }

    // Handle pointer down
    public void OnPointerDown()
    {
        // skip if the button is not interactable
        if(!button.enabled || !button.interactable) return;

        // skip if already rotating
        if(isPressed) return;

        StartCoroutine(PressedRoutine());
        isPressed= true;

    }

    // Handle pointer up
    public void OnPointerUp()
    {
        isPressed= false;
    }

    // Handle pointer exit
    public void OnPointerExit()
    {
        isPressed= false;
    }

    private IEnumerator RotateRoutine()
    {
        // repeatedly call whilePressed until button isPressed turns false
        while(isPressed)
        {
            // break the routine if button was disabled meanwhile
            if(!button.enabled || !button.interactable)
            {
                isPressed = false;
                yield break;
            }

            // call whatever is referenced in whilePressed;
            whilePressed.Invoke();

            // leave here, render the frame and continue in the next frame
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

or you could do the same in `Update` again as well

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Button))]
public class HoldableButton : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{
    public UnityEvent whilePressed;

    private bool isPressed;
    private Button button;

    private void Awake()
    {
        button = GetComponent<Button>();

        if(!button)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Oh no no Button component on this object :O",this);
        }
    }


    private void Update()
    {
        // if button is not interactable do nothing
        if(!button.enabled || !button.interactable) return;

        // if not rotating do nothing
        if(!isPressed) return;

        // call whatever is referenced in whilePressed;
        whilePressed.Invoke();
    }

    // Handle pointer down
    public void OnPointerDown()
    {
        // enable pressed
        isPressed= true;
    }

    // Handle pointer up
    public void OnPointerUp()
    {
        // disable pressed
        isPressed= false;
    }

    // Handle pointer exit
    public void OnPointerExit()
    {
        // disable pressed
        isPressed= false;
    }
}
```

Place this component next to a `Button` component. You don't have to reference anything in `onClick` just leave it empty. Instead reference something in `onPressed`. Keep the `Button` component though since it handles also the UI style for us (like hover changes the color/sprite etc.)

---

Again: The `Update` solutions might look cleaner/simplier for now but are not as efficient (in this usecase) and easy to controll (this might be opinion based) as the Coroutine solutions.

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped for me. :)

Comment: @ImaniAbayakoon Glad to help! If this resolves your question please feel free to mark the answer as the accepted one :)

Answer (score 0):

Please search on the article regarding the key press functionalities . It would help you a lot in finding your answer. Update is used if we need to do something continuously in our project where as the key pressed is used when we have do it for once

[image: the Example for the Update issue]

this example is also being used to resolve your issue and use this Script when a specific button is is being pressed

Comment: Your method `CheckInput` anyway would have to be called in `Update` or another repeatedly called method in order to track the key event in every frame! However the question was about a `UI.Button` and the `onClick` event rather than using `Input`. Anyway the main issue was actually that the OP's method `Rotate` requires to be called repeatedly in order to work properly.

Comment: ok Buddy , I have searched and found a very good video for you regarding the movement of the game object through different functionalities . The key press always work in the update method but to move the game object there are different methods explain in the below video . I made my game and used the start method but i called the update method as it always work frame by frame .  and in the update method we can apply different functionalities 
link 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tNtOcDryKv4

Comment: Unfortunately that is not what the OP asked about. As already said he wanted to know how to use the `Rotate` method without calling it in `Update` but instead controll the rotation via a `UI.Button` ... it has nothing todo with calling any of the `Input.GetKeyDown` or `Input.GetButton` methods

Comment: It might be more useful to actually insert the code itself versus a screen shot.

Comment: screenshot help me to save my time and focus on other key problems but thanks for the concern